# Eigenvalues of $\pmatrix{1&1\\1&2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, maxima-software

I use maxima for calculation eigenvalues of this matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and I get $\frac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and then $[1,1]$ for some reason.

Namely:

```
(%i1) matrix(
 [1,1], 
 [1,2]
);
                                   [ 1  1 ]
(%o1)                              [      ]
                                   [ 1  2 ]
(%i2) eigenvalues(%);
                        sqrt(5) - 3  sqrt(5) + 3
(%o2)               [[- -----------, -----------], [1, 1]]
                             2            2
```

What does the $[1,1]$ mean? I'm confused.

Comment: I'm not expert on maxima but I think that this is the multiplicity.

Comment: It might be the multiplicity of the eigenvalue.  Check $\pmatrix{1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1}$ to double check. I'm guessing it should give you `[[0,3],[2,1]]`

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, yeah. I get [[0,3],[2,1]].

Comment: Yes. Obviously it's multiplicity. Thanks.

Comment: One could also Read The Friendly Manual:  http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_23.html#eigenvalues